# How would you implement a breadcrumb helper in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, navigation

I know you could make a helper pretty easily given the data. So, if possible, please only submit answers that also include getting the data.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We are using an action filter for this.

...

```
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var controller = (Controller) filterContext.Controller;
        Breadcrumb[] breadcrumbs = _breadcrumbManager.PushBreadcrumb(_breadcrumbLinkText);
        controller.ViewData.Add(breadcrumbs);
    }
```

before you mention it, I too have a distaste for service location in the filter attributes - but we are left with few options.  IBreadcrumbManager looks like this:

```
public interface IBreadcrumbManager
{
    Breadcrumb[] PushBreadcrumb(string linkText);
}
```

The implementation puts Breadcrumb objects into the Session. The Url is `HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl`

Comment: Is the implementation of IBreadcrumbManager somewhere we can look at? Where does _breakcrumbLinkText come from?

Comment: could you show a more detailed example of this solution to breadcrumb helper? Do you have any test solution you could share maybe? I don't really get it with the interface _breadcrumbManager/IBreadcrumbManager
..

Answer (score 2):

@Chris: something like this:

```
        <% 
        foreach (var item in ViewData.Get<Breadcrumb[]>())
            {
        %>
                <a href="<%= Server.HtmlEncode(item.Url) %>"><%= item.LinkText %></a> &raquo;
        <% 
            } 
        %>
```