# ASP.NET MVC - Simple Breadcrumbs (SiteMap)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, sitemap

I have developed a ASP.NET MVC 2 application and I want to put a simple breadcrumbs (sitemap) in each page like this:

Home > Movies > Details

It is equal the URL: http://localhost/home/movies/details

How can I achieve it? I would like to put it in my master page.

Thanks!

Comment: SiteMap? Don't you mean breadcrumbs?

Comment: yes you are correctly, breadcrumbs. Actually I'm web forms developer. There, it is known SiteMap.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can dynamic breadcrumbs be achieved with ASP.net MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066777/how-can-dynamic-breadcrumbs-be-achieved-with-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How would you implement a breadcrumb helper in asp.net mvc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66009/how-would-you-implement-a-breadcrumb-helper-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: yes, it is duplicated. What I need to do?

Comment: I don't think there is anything you can do... just wait for other users to come along and vote to close it too. :-)

Comment: My pleasure, hope you enjoy using Stackoverflow :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is always equal to the URL, the absolute simplest thing would be to make use of that by using something like this:

```
var menuitems = Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Split("/".ToCharArray(),
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

`menuitems` would now contain the menu items you need to perform a simple foreach loop and build your menu.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using [**MVCSiteMapProvider**](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/MvcSiteMapProvider-MVC3). It's available as a NuGet package.

It can be used to generate breadcrumbs (which you are probably asking about) and also site maps.

> MvcSiteMapProvider is, as the name
>   implies, an ASP.NET MVC
>   SiteMapProvider implementation for the
>   ASP.NET MVC framework. Targeted at
>   ASP.NET MVC 2, it provides sitemap XML
>   functionality and interoperability
>   with the classic ASP.NET sitemap
>   controls, like the SiteMapPath control
>   for rendering breadcrumbs and the Menu
>   control.
>
> Based on areas, controller and action
>   method names rather than hardcoded URL
>   references, sitemap nodes are
>   completely dynamic based on the
>   routing engine used in an application.
>   The dynamic character of ASP.NET MVC
>   is followed in the MvcSiteMapProvider:
>   there are numerous extensibility
>   points that allow you to extend the
>   basic functionality offered.

Comment: I have bad experiences with MvcSiteMapProvider when number of dynamic nodes is very high (20.000+).