# Asp.Net MVC 2 Creating BreadCrumbs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 2 in my project. I want to create bread crumbs for our categories. But I want to bring the bread crumb programatically. How can I make this work in a User Control ?

Answer (score 2):

There's a nuget package for an ASP.NET MVC site map that may be of help:

http://nuget.org/List/Packages/MvcSiteMapProvider

It's also referenced in this SO question:

[ASP.NET MVC - Simple Breadcrumbs (SiteMap)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317238/asp-net-mvc-simple-breadcrumbs-sitemap)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

We're using the [ASP.NET MVC Site Map Project](http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/) to generate our breadcrumbs. There is a section on [how to generate dynamic site maps](http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Dynamic%20sitemaps&referringTitle=Home) on the project website.